# Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError in ListingsController#update missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I am getting error as:

> Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError in ListingsController#update missing
>   region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']

I've been stuck at trying to get my S3 attached to paperclip for about 3 days now. This is my latest error.This error is from my local. Heroku doesnt give me an error; however, after checking my picture url it does not have s3 in it. My brain is completely fried trying to figure this out.

**config/env/pro.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do

config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_host_name: "s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    s3_credentials: {
        bucket: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
        access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
        s3_region: ENV['us-east-1']
        }

    }
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in       config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
   # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled =      ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

 # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is   missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved   to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [   'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-  Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic       information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "Joeget_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

 # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
 # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate   delivery to raise delivery errors.
 # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
   # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

   # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

   # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
   config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

 # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
 # require 'syslog/logger'
 # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new   'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
   logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
   logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] =   ':http://joeget.s3.amazonaws.com' 
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = "#    {Rails.root}/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
s3_region: ENV['us-east-1']
```

to

```
s3_region: 'us-east-1'
```

or

```
s3_region: ENV['AWS_REGION']
# You need to set AWS_REGION=us-east-1
```